# Multi threading for loops in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, for-loop

I am use VB.net to help solve some equations by interating them. It is taking a long time using one thread so I hoping someone can help me Multithread the code. Here is an over simplified example of what I am trying to achieve.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Evens(6) As Integer
    Dim Odds(6) As Integer

    For i = 0 To 6
        Evens(i) = i * 2
        Odds(i) = i * 2 + 1
    Next

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Evens = RunLoop(Evens, 0, 6)    'The best way to Multi thread this part please.
    Odds = RunLoop(Odds, 0, 6)
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    For i = 0 To 6
        TextBox1.AppendText(Evens(i) & vbNewLine)
        TextBox1.AppendText(Odds(i) & vbNewLine)
    Next


End Sub

Private Function RunLoop(Numbers() As Integer, Start As Integer, Last As Integer)

    For i = Start To Last
        Numbers(i) *= Numbers(i)
    Next

    Return Numbers

End Function
```

End Class

I need to past data back to the main thread, so I can compare the results from each thread against each other. I have created a class for the data I need to past back from the function.

The time spend in each for loop can be different lengths.

Comment: Check [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could run them in parallel, with a [Parallel For Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for(v=vs.110).aspx), just need to be careful that the order things are executed isn't important. This loop only guarantees that each item in the iteration will be done, they will not happen in any kind of specific order...

To implement that with your code, you would simply need to make the following change:

```
Private Function RunLoop(Numbers() As Integer, Start As Integer, Last As Integer)

    'For i = Start To Last
    '    Numbers(i) *= Numbers(i)
    'Next

    'Run every iteration in the loop in parallel:
    Parallel.For(Start, Last + 1, Sub(i) Numbers(i) *= Numbers(i))

    Return Numbers

End Function
```